# Data via jQuery AJAX to Pyramid backend woes

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, pyramid

So, I'm trying to post the value of an element with an id of "AltTitle" via AJAX back to a Pyramid backend.  With the code below, Python receives a request.param of AlternativeTitle.  That's it.  No value.  I'm stuck.  I want to learn how to build a dictionary of AJAX data so I can then pass all values back to Python, but so far, I can't get one to work.  Any help appreciated....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/edit/29241",
            data:{
                "AlternativeTitle": $("#AltTitle").html()
            },
            success:function(result){
                alert( result );
                }
        });
    });
});
<p id="AltTitle" contenteditable=True>Existing Title</p>
<button>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the {} are causing the issue. This could be because the jQuery is inside a Jinja2 template, but even adding {% raw %} didn't change the outcome. By changing the script to:

```
data:"AlternativeTitle:" + alttitle + '&' "othervalue" + otherval,
```

I got the serialized version at the server. I am yet to write this back to the db, but I think it will work now. Thanks Fosco and Antoine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getting the value first?  Give this a shot:

```
    var alttitle = $("#AltTitle").html();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/edit/29241",
        data:{ AlternativeTitle : alttitle },
        success:function(result){
            alert( result );
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Fosco, but I still just get the string `AlternativeTitle`.  Any other clues??

Comment: @MFB can you show me the python code that is receiving this ajax call?  I'm no python guru but it would help, seems like the issue is there.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the {} are causing the issue.  This could be because the jQuery is inside a Jinja2 template, but even adding {% raw %} didn't change the outcome.  By changing the script to `data:"AlternativeTitle:" + alttitle + '&' "othervalue" + otherval,` I got the serialized version at the server.  I am yet to write this back to the db, but I think it will work now.  Thank you HEAPS for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is look up the value of `$("#AltTitle").html()` by typing it in the Javascript console of your browser (Ctrl+I in Chrome). Then, if the result is what you expect, I would check for the value posted in the developer tools of your browser to make sure the value of AlternativeTitle that is posted is what you expect. In Chrome, you will see your HTTP requests in the Network tab of the developer tools. Then I would have a look at the code server side.

But there's not so much that can go wrong server side, since you say that `request.params['AlternativeTitle']` is there but empty.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the {} are causing the issue. This could be because the jQuery is inside a Jinja2 template, but even adding {% raw %} didn't change the outcome. By changing the script to data:"AlternativeTitle:" + alttitle + '&' "othervalue" + otherval, I got the serialized version at the server. I am yet to write this back to the db, but I think it will work now. Thank you HEAPS for your help.